# kubernetes pod talking to a localhost port

Tags: kubectl, portforwarding

I have a celery instance running inside a pod in local kubernetes cluster whereas the redis server/broker it connects to is started on my localhost:6379 without kubernetes . How can i get my k8 pod to talk to locally deployed redis?

Comment: Why redis is not in pod ?

Comment: I was testing something specific to celery when deployed as a pod. Hence didn't put other application components to k8. Was wondering if it can work without redis also being deployed as pod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) and an [Endpoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) with statically defined IP address of the node where the redis server is running.

---

I've created an example to illustrate you how it works.

First, I created a `Headless Service` and an `Endpoint`.
**NOTE:** `Endpoint` has the IP address of the node where redis server is running:

```
# example.yml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: redis
    port: 6379
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: default
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.156.0.58 # your node's IP address
    ports:
      - port: 6379
        name: redis
        protocol: TCP
```

After creating above resources, we are able to resolve the `redis` service name to the IP address:

```
# kubectl get svc,ep redis
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/redis   ClusterIP   None         <none>        6379/TCP   28m

NAME              ENDPOINTS          AGE
endpoints/redis   10.156.0.58:6379   28m

# kubectl run dnsutils --image=gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3 -it --rm
/ # nslookup redis
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   redis.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.156.0.58
```

Additionally, if your redis server is only listening on `localhost`, you need to modify the `iptables` rules. To configure port forwarding from port `6379` (default redis port) to `localhost` you can use:
**NOTE:** Instead of `10.156.0.58` use the IP address of the node where your redis server is running.

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.156.0.58 --dport 6379 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:6379
```

As you can see, it is easier if redis is listening not only on the `localhost`, as we don't have to modify the `iptables` rules then.

Finally, let's see if we can connect from Pod to the redis server on the host machine:

```
# kubectl exec -it redis-client -- bash
root@redis-client:/# redis-cli -h redis
redis:6379> SET key1 "value1"
OK
```

Comment: Thanks! @WytrzymałyWiktor Yes it does!

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically assign the node's IP address in the spec?