# Expose port on machine to kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssh, portforwarding, k3s

**UPDATE:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66314515/5950725) is the solution.

### The setup

- k3s
- Traefik
- Following this tutorial https://blog.rousek.name/2017/01/21/expose-local-port-as-https-endpoint/

### What I'm trying to achieve

Expose my local port to the world to accept webhooks from third parties.

```
     Webhook GET request ──► Remote server ──► Traefik ──► Pod A ───┐
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
└──► Pod A uses nginx to forward to localhost:5000 (inside pod) ────┐
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
└──► Somehow, k8s reaches localhost:5000 of remote server (not k8s) ─┐
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
└──► SSH port forwards to local dev machine
```

How can I acheive the `Somehow, k8s reaches localhost of remote server (not k8s)` part?
Put another way, how can one expose a port of the physical remote server to a pod inside k8s?

Comment: not understand well enough still trying, localhost:500 is a service or just endpoint? if it's a service you can write the script and access the remote server. if it's not service you can directly move the request from nginx to remote server. or you are looking for secure way to expose remote server ?

Comment: @Harsh Manvar The request has to go through k8s